# Using chipboard screws and plugs in a dot & dab wall

Tags: screws, mounting

I have a [dot & dab wall](https://www.diydoctor.org.uk/projects/dot-and-dab-plasterboard.htm) and am installing a radiator onto it. I had a rummage around and found a "chipboard screws and plug" set. Using the included wall plugs, would these be suitable for securing the radiator to the wall?

I have had a Google around about different screw types and all of the articles/guides I have read talk about the thread types and why they are good for their respective uses. Surely this is less important when being installed into a wall plug?

Comment: in a dot-and-dab wall you've got half an inch of platerboard then a quarter inch or so of adhesive or void before you get to the masonry.  if the screws are long it could work.  how much does the radiator weigh? how big and what shape are the mounting holes?

Comment: It's 22kg when empty. The holes are circular, and about 7/8mm diameter.

Comment: What's behind the drywall? Hollow cinderblocks, concrete, bricks?...

Comment: If the radiator is sitting on the floor and only attached to the wall to keep it from tipping, then a simple "rawl plug"/"molly bolt"/similar should do the trick. Needs more detail to answer the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

A light-weight electric radiator could be mounted using drywall anchors or ordinary wall plugs.

For this heavy hydronic radiator it needs to be securely attached to the masonry without compressing the drywall.

There are three-part wall plugs that can do this (eg the "Corefix" mentioned on the dot-annd-dab page linked in the question), or you could use an expanding bolt with three nuts, one against the masonry and two to hold the radiator. An "8mm" expanding bolt will have a 6mm shaft so that would work with your mounting holes.